# Beginner Software RE help, RAM Addresses, library loading, where to start?

Tags: unix, reverse-engineering, code-injection, ram, dylib

To start this off, I use OS X which is a UNIX based system.

I have beginner theoretical knowledge in C++ and would like to expand my knowledge by software reverse engineering. Every guide I get into seems to jump in half way and I seem to miss a giant gap of information required to start up. What my end goal is to successfully build a working dylib for any application. Where do i start with learning Ram addresses, how do they work, how are libraries loaded and what the actual hell do I start reading, what subject. Everything I've learned so far has a distinct start point, certain syntax but I just find everything uses terminology I don't understand. I find myself just branching off more and more because an article used a keyword I don't understand, I google it, the other one uses five I don't understand and I just get stuck. The application under question does not have changing memory addresses, but I would also like to learn how to compensate for it using offsets.

*Where do I start?!*

Comment: A good `reverse engineer` would be a software engineer with 5-20 yrs of experience. You need to understand how all of these technologies work (mostly) before you can try to build theories about deconstructing an existing system. Just keeping up with current technology (once you have a job that gets in the way), will be a good challenge for your first years after completing a CS degree. I'd recommend posting this question to Quora.com, as that site thrives on this sort of question. It is probably already answered there. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you get started with reverse engeneering you'll need more than a theoretical knowledge of the C language. Forget C++ for now, C is simpler and it's so low level that once you master it you'll understand how programs work under the hood. Get you a copy of The C Programming Language by Brian Kernighan and Dennis Ritchie and go through the whole book.

Once you feel confortable writting C programs get familiar with UNIX standards like POSIX and then move on to OS X specific stuff. The best resource for OS X programming is http://developer.apple.com. The link below explains how dynamic libraries work on OS X. Once you get a good understanding of C it will all make sense.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/DynamicLibraries/100-Articles/OverviewOfDynamicLibraries.html